# NMinimize is very slow

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, minimization

You are my last hope.
In my university there are no people able to answer my question.
I've got a function quite complex depending on 6 paramethers a0,a1,a2,b0,b1,b2 that minimize the delta of pression, volume liquid and volume vapor calculated by a rather new equation of state.
NMinimize is very slow and I could not do any considerations about this equation because timing is very high.
In the code there are some explanations and some problems concerning my code.
On my knees I pray you to help me.
I'm sorry, but after 4 months on construction of these equation I could not test it. And frustration is increasing day after day!

```
Clear["Global`*"];

 data = {{100., 34.376, 0.036554, 23.782}, {105., 56.377, 0.037143, 
 15.116}, {110., 88.13, 0.037768, 10.038}, {115., 132.21, 0.038431,
 6.9171}, {120., 191.43, 0.039138, 4.9183}, {125., 268.76, 
  0.039896, 3.5915}, {130., 367.32, 0.040714, 2.6825}, {135., 
 490.35, 0.0416, 2.0424}, {140., 641.18, 0.042569, 1.5803}, {145., 
823.22, 0.043636, 1.2393}, {150., 1040., 0.044825, 
0.98256}, {155., 1295., 0.046165, 0.78568}, {160., 1592.1, 
0.047702, 0.63206}, {165., 1935.1, 0.0495, 0.51014}, {170., 
2328.3, 0.051667, 0.41163}, {175., 2776.5, 0.054394, 
0.33038}, {180., 3285.2, 0.058078, 0.26139}, {185., 3861.7, 
0.063825, 0.19945}, {190., 4518.6, 0.079902, 0.12816}};
tvector = data[[All, 1]];(*K*)
pvector = 
data[[All, 2]];(*KPa*)
vlvector = data[[All, 3]];(*L/mol*)
vvvector = 
data[[All, 4]];
(*L/mol.*)
r = 8.314472;
tc = 190.56;
avvicinamento = Length[tvector] - 3;
trexp = Take[tvector, avvicinamento]/tc;
vlexp = Take[vlvector, avvicinamento];
vvexp = Take[vvvector, avvicinamento];
zeri = Table[i*0., {i, avvicinamento}];
pexp = Take[pvector, avvicinamento];
(*Function for calculation of Fugacity of CSD Equation*)
(*Function for calculation of Fugacity of CSD Equation*)
fug[v_, p_, t_, a_, b_] := 
Module[{y, z, vbv, vb, f1, f2, f3, f4, f}, y = b/(4 v);
z = (p v)/(r t);
vbv = Log[(v + b)/v];
vb = v + b;
f1 = (4*y - 3*y^2)/(1 - y)^2;
f2 = (4*y - 2*y^2)/(1 - y)^3;
f3 = (2*vbv)/(r t*b)*a;
f4 = (vbv/b - 1/vb)/(r t)*a;
f = f1 + f2 - f3 + f4 - Log[z];
Exp[f]]

(*g Minimize the equality of fugacity*)
g[p_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ, a0_?NumericQ, a1_?NumericQ, a2_?NumericQ, 
b0_?NumericQ, b1_?NumericQ, b2_?NumericQ] := Module[{},
a = a0*Exp[a1*t + a2*t^2];
b = b0 + b1*t + b2*t^2;
csd = a/(r*t*(b + v)) - (-(b^3/(64*v^3)) + b^2/(16*v^2) + 
    b/(4*v) + 1)/(1 - b/(4*v))^3 + (p*v)/(r*t);
vol = NSolve[csd == 0 && v > 0, v, Reals];
sol = v /. vol;
(*If[Length[sol]==1,Interrupt[];Print["Sol==1"]];*)
vliquid = Min[sol];
vvapor = Max[sol];
fl = fug[vliquid, p, t, a, b];
fv = fug[vvapor, p, t, a, b];
(*Print[{t,p,vol,Abs[fl-fv]}];*)
Abs[fl - fv]];
(*This function minimize the pcalc-pexp and vcalc-vexp *)
hope[a0_?NumericQ, a1_?NumericQ, a2_?NumericQ, b0_?NumericQ, 
b1_?NumericQ, b2_?NumericQ] := 
Module[{}, 
pp[a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2] := 
Table[FindRoot[{g[p, tvector[[i]], a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2]}, 
{p,pvector[[i]]}],{i,avvicinamento}];
pressioni1 = pp[a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2];
pcalc = p /. pressioni1;
differenza = ((pcalc - pexp)/pexp)^2;
If[MemberQ[differenza, 0.], 
differenza = zeri + RandomReal[{100000, 500000}];(*
First problem:
As I've FindRoot that finds the solutions equal to the starting \
point, I don't want these kind of solutions and with this method - \
+RandomReal[{100000,500000}] - 
a keep away this solutions.Is it right? *)
deltap = Total[differenza],
differenzanonzero = Select[differenza, # > 0 &];
csd1[a_, b_, p_, t_] := 
 a/(r*t*(b + v)) - (-(b^3/(64*v^3)) + b^2/(16*v^2) + b/(4*v) + 
     1)/(1 - b/(4*v))^3 + (p*v)/(r*t);(*Funzione CSD*)
volumi = 
 Table[NSolve[csd1[a, b, pcalc[[i]], tvector[[i]]], v, Reals], {i,
    avvicinamento}];
soluzioni = v /. volumi;
vvcalc = Table[Max[soluzioni[[i]]], {i, avvicinamento}];
vlcalc = Table[Min[soluzioni[[i]]], {i, avvicinamento}];
deltavl = Total[((vlexp - vlcalc)/vlcalc)^2];
deltavv = Total[((vvexp - vvcalc)/vvcalc)^2];
deltap = Total[differenza];
Print[a0, "  ", b0, "   ", delta];
delta = 0.1*deltavl + 0.1*deltavv + deltap]];
NMinimize[{hope[a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2], 
500 < a0 < 700 && -0.01 < a1 < -1.0*10^-5 && -10^-5 < a2 < -10^-7 &&
0.0010 < b0 < 0.1 && -0.0010 < b1 < -1.0*10^-5 && 
10^-9 < b2 < 10^-7}, {a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2}]
```

Thanks in advance!
Mariano Pierantozzi
PhD Student in chemical Engineering

Comment: You could try posting it at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions, but don't expect us there to analyze your code. Dissect it and post there SELF CONTAINED small chunks of code where you need help

Comment: Sometimes large and/or difficult problems take a long time to solve.  Why do you think your problem should be solved more quickly than it is ?  What have you done to investigate the options to `NMinimize` which may (possibly) help you to make your program quicker ?  Mathematica's capabilities are often very impressive but you can't realistically expect it to solve all your problems for you, sometimes (most times) you have to help it with your deep understanding of your problem.

Comment: I've followed all your suggestions. Thanks a lot.
[link]http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18561/compile-doesent-work